# Linq query Contains

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp-classic, contains

i have an issue with this query

```
  var myList = (from p in db.Full
                      where (p.date_reception > begin & p.date_reception < end
                            & !p.mc_owner.Contains("NULL") & !p.mc_owner.Contains(""))

                      group p by p.mc_owner into g
                      orderby g.Count() descending
                      select new
                      {
                          Ownerx = g.Key,
                          countx = g.Count()
                      }).ToList();
```

Everything works well without adding !p.mc_owner.Contains(""), but once i do it just shows no results

Comment: what is the type of mc_owner?

Comment: varchar in the database and string in the model

Comment: then why are you checking your string contains an empty string? do you mean `p.mc_owner != ""` ?

Comment: why not just !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.mc_owner)

Comment: still no result i have i field in the DB that contains value "NULL" and another which is empty , and i want to exclude them from the query

Comment: You can use `HasValue`  property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any string with value will contain empty string. For example next testcode will print true.

```
    string a = "abc";
    Console.WriteLine(a.Contains(""));
    Console.ReadLine();
```

You probably meant to write:

```
p.mc_owner != ""
```

or it is better to write

```
!string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.mc_owner)
```

I guess with .contains("NULL") you wanted to leave out NULL values and not the string "NULL". Also I would && instead of &. I suggest to rewrite to:

```
(p.date_reception > begin && p.date_reception < end
                        && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.mc_owner))
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this is:

```
   var myList = (from p in db.Full
                      where (p.date_reception > begin & p.date_reception < end
                            & !p.mc_owner.Contains("NULL") & !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.mc_owner))

                      group p by p.mc_owner into g
                      orderby g.Count() descending
                      select new
                      {
                          Ownerx = g.Key,
                          countx = g.Count()
                      }).ToList();
```

Comment: You need to show exactly where that fragment is to go by showing it in context with the OP's code